# Can you add money to a CD

Tags: united-states, certificate-of-deposit

Is it possible to add money to a CD like you would a money market or do you have to wait until the CD matures to make changes? I've found interest rates to be higher on CDs but not being able to add money for several years makes it less appealing.

Comment: Even if you could, with rates going up, you don't want to add money to an existing CD. New CD are very likely to be getting a higher rate than the one you already have. And probably doing so with a shorter term. You can get 2% or more on a one year CD and 3% on a 5 year. How much is your current CD giving you and what is the duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't generally add money to a CD, you can simply buy additional CD's.

For example, I keep a portion of my emergency fund in CDs, every couple months I buy/open a 5-year CD, I haven't been doing this long enough for any to have matured, but depending on rates in the future when they start maturing I'd just used the proceeds to buy another at that point.

I see references on a number of sites to CD's that you can add money to, but I haven't come across a reference to an actual product, so there may be some sort of CD that allows adding funds, but haven't seen any specifics, I'd imagine they come with lower rates.

Comment: Navy Federal Credit Union [offers certificates](https://www.navyfederal.org/products-services/checking-savings/certificates.php) that you can add to anytime during the term. I've had one since last May and I've added funds to it periodically over that time.

Answer (score 1):

Many banks encourage customers to use a laddered approach to their CDs.

If you wish to add funds to your CD instead purchase a new CD with a maturity date near to the maturity date of the first CD. Or purchase  new CD with the same length, but would now have a maturity date farther in the future.

That being said there are several altenative to non-flexible CDs:

- There are CDs that allow you to "bump up" the rate once during the life of the CD.
- There are also CD like programs that allow you to have a certificate linked to a series of monthly deposits.
- There are ones that are linked to your direct deposit.

These types of certificates have a lower rate than a non-flexible CD, because you are trading rate for that flexibility

Comment: There are some Add-On CDs allow you to add the extra money.  They tend to  have secondary rules for this additional money such as pegging the rate to the time remaining (longer term rates are higher than short term so adding money to a 5 year CD after 4 years will not get you the higher rate).  Read the fine print.